# parse object not receiving

Tags: android, parse-platform

I get the Id for a parse object from a previous activity and store it in "obj"
I know the Id is being passed by checking but am getting null pointer exceptions because my four strings restName,restAddress,restCuisine and restLocation are empty even after i try assigning the corresponding values by my parse query.

```
package com.example.gastronomaapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.parse.GetCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

public class SingleRestraunt extends ActionBarActivity {
    private GoogleMap map;
    TextView resteName, resteCuisine, resteLocation, resteAddress;
    String restName = "nothing", obj, restCuisine = "nothing",
            restLocation = "nothing", restAddress = "nothing";
    Double Lang, Long;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_restraunt);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        obj = i.getStringExtra("restName");
        getDetails(obj);

    }

    private void getDetails(String obj) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Restraunt");
        query.getInBackground(obj, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    restName = object.getString("Name");
                    restCuisine = object.getString("Cuisine");
                    restLocation = object.getString("Location");
                    restAddress = object.getString("Address");
                    Lang = object.getDouble("Lat");
                    Long = object.getDouble("Long");
                } else {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        // prepareMap(Lang, Long);
        addData();

    }

    public void addData() {
        resteName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.restrauntName);
        resteCuisine = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.restrauntCuisine);
        resteLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.restrauntLocation);
        resteAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.restrauntAddress);
        resteName.setText(restName);
        resteCuisine.setText(restCuisine);
        resteLocation.setText(restLocation);
        resteAddress.setText(restAddress);
    }

    public void prepareMap(Double Lang, Double Long) {
        final LatLng REST = new LatLng(Lang, Long);
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(REST)
                .title("Here"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(REST, 15));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.single_restraunt, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void Submit(View v) {
        final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.review);
        final EditText edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rName);
        String rName = edit1.getText().toString();
        String review = edit.getText().toString();

        ParseObject newReview = new ParseObject("Reviews");
        newReview.put("Name", rName);
        newReview.put("review", review);
        newReview.saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

I added the nothing value to all my strings initially to debug. And when running promptly the nothing is printed indicating that the query is not making any change to my strings.Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you initialize the parse? e.g  Parse.initialize(this, Init.PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, Init.PARSE_CLIENT_ID);
  PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, Splash.class);
  ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();

Comment: Yes I have,parse calls seems to be working in another acitivity just not this one. I'm getting more curious as to whether I'm using the right object

Comment: Ive tried your suggestion and it didnt solve my issue. Any other suggestions?

Comment: First question, Have you update your PARSE SDK? or create a class which extends Application. Second what is the type of your column "Lat" and "Long" in parse?